# Heroku and PSQL - "Cannot read property 'query' of null"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I'm having a problem when I follow the Heroku tutorial with DB.
First error I got was that pg.connect was invalid from PSQL 7. I tried to change this and using pool instead. However, I can´t make it work and I don´t know why.

Client is 'null' so I get

```
Listening on 5000 C:\Users\a491601\OneDrive - AF\Privat\SHT\node-js-getting- started\index.js:21 

client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result) { 

TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of null
```

Code:

```
const cool = require('cool-ascii-faces')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
var app = express();
app
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/cool', (req, res) => res.send(cool()))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))



app.get('/db', function (request, response) {
  var pg = require('pg')
  var pool = new pg.Pool(process.env.DATABASE_URL)
  pool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
    client.query('SELECT * FROM test_table', function(err, result) {
      done();
      if (err)
       { console.error(err); response.send("Error " + err); }
      else
       { response.render('pages/db', {results: result.rows} ); }
    });
  });
  pool.end()
});
```

Please help me, I've tried different thing for hour now, but I can't get i right.

Comment: Can you check if there is any error when the pool trying to connect? Right before `client.query`, add `console.log(err)`

Comment: Hmm, got an error: Password authentication failed for user "XXX" at Connection.parseE (C:\XXX\node-js-getting-started\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:567:11)

Comment: So check your db url to make sure it's correct

Comment: If i add an console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL) I get "undefined". However, if I run "heroku config" I get an expected result. So it seems that process.env.DATABASE_URL exists, but I cannot use it?